# How to upgrade to PHP 5.5.25(The Latest Stable Released Version of PHP) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit OS?

Tags: 12.04, php, 64-bit, repository, php-fpm

I tried following commands but after running these commands I got upgraded from **PHP 5.5.23** to **PHP 5.5.24**. I want to upgrade to **PHP 5.5.25** which is a latest stable released version.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The following is the output of `apt-cache policy php5`:

```
php5:
  Installed: 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  Candidate: 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Please suggest me the way to upgrade my system to the latest stable release of PHP i.e. **PHP 5.5.25**.

Thanks.

Comment: @kos: My question is not a duplicate of  How do I install latest PHP in supported Ubuntu versions (like 5.4.x in Ubuntu 12.04)?  because I've done the same thing mentioned in the answer of this question but still I'm not getting upgraded to the latest stable released version of PHP i.e. 5.5.25

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I retracted my close vote. Most likely 5.5.25 is not in that repository yet. Let me check this

Comment: @kos it's there alright: `5.5.25+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1`  is the PPA's version of `php5`.

Comment: @muru Yes but the latest build failed for all versions: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75

Comment: @kos in that case we should contact the maintainer.

Comment: Hey folks isn't there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @muru I think he's aware already? I don't know how private repositories are handled. @ OP In short, until the mantainer is able to build the package successfully, you can always compile PHP yourself

Comment: JFTR launchpad team broke alternative dependency handling (there was locales-all | language-pack-de before) between php 5.5.24 and 5.5.25 and launchpad doesn't send an error email in case the build is waiting for dependency, so the only way to know that something broke is to check the PPAs by hand (or by getting notified by other people).

P.S.: I voted close since I don't think that the "Contact user" button on https://launchpad.net/~ondrej deserves a separate question on AskUbuntu...

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the question, `PHP 5.5.25`'s package was broken on the repository.

Quoting [Ondřej Surý's comment to the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627653/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-5-25the-latest-stable-released-version-of-php-on-ubunt#comment892207_627653):

> JFTR launchpad team broke alternative dependency handling (there was locales-all | language-pack-de before) between php 5.5.24 and 5.5.25 [...].

Thanks to [hbdgaf](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/hbdgaf), who [kindly asked Ondřej Surý about this on Launchpad](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21812120#21812120), and thanks to Ondřej Surý, who [kindly fixed this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21830651#21830651), quoting Ondřej Surý's response:

> Lovely, launchpad broke it the builds.
>
> I have patched the packages to not depend on locales-all.
>
> Cheers, 
>   Ondrej

The package is now fixed and you should be able to install it using `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade php5`.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade php5 but still the PHP is not upgraded to 5.5.25. Following is the output after executing this command :Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: I suspect you didn't `sudo apt-get update` first

Comment: @PHPLover What hbdgaf said, after `sudo apt-get update` `PHP 5.5.25` shows up as a candidate for `PHP 5.5` in my `apt-cache policy php5` output.